# React native elements header background image

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I made a header using react native elements, and I want to add background image into it. Is there anyway to do it?

I am using react-native-elements: "^0.19.1"

Here is my header code

```
     render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight, backgroundColor: color.light_grey }}>
                    <Header
                        leftComponent={this.props.left ? this.props.left : <IconWrapper name='menu' color='black' size={28} style={styles.icon} onPress={() => Actions.drawerOpen()} />}
                        centerComponent={<Text style={styles.headerText}>{this.props.title}</Text>}
                        rightComponent={this.props.right ? this.props.right : <IconWrapper name='handbag' type='simple-line-icon' color='black' size={28} style={styles.icon} onPress={() => Actions.BagContents()} />}
                        outerContainerStyles={[styles.headerOuterContainer, { height: 0.08 * windowHeight() }]}
                    />                
                
            </View>
        ) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ReactNative's component `ImageBackground` you can use it.

like this,

```
<ImageBackground source={...} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Header
        leftComponent={this.props.left ? this.props.left : <IconWrapper name='menu' color='black' size={28} style={styles.icon} onPress={() => Actions.drawerOpen()} />}
        centerComponent={<Text style={styles.headerText}>{this.props.title}</Text>}
        rightComponent={this.props.right ? this.props.right : <IconWrapper name='handbag' type='simple-line-icon' color='black' size={28} style={styles.icon} onPress={() => Actions.BagContents()} />}
        outerContainerStyles={[styles.headerOuterContainer, { height: 0.08 * windowHeight() }]}
     /> 
</ImageBackground>
```

You can always style it your way.

Comment: it doesn't work. It only add imagebackground under the header not in the header

Comment: make your header style `backgroundColor:'transparent'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own `<Header/>` component, probably will take you more time but you will be able to understand it and edit it as you like. I created a simple Header component to show you how you can accomplish adding a background image to your header. See the snack [@abranhe/stackoverflow-56729412](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56729412)

**Header.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

export default class Header extends Component {
  renderContent() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <View style={styles.left}>{this.props.left}</View>
        <View style={styles.center}>{this.props.center}</View>
        <View style={styles.right}>{this.props.right}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderHeaderWithImage() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={this.props.imageSource}>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }

  renderHeaderWithoutImage() {
    return (
      <View style={[{ backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8' }, styles.container]}>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.image
      ? this.renderHeaderWithImage()
      : this.renderHeaderWithoutImage();
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    top: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    borderBottom: 1,
    borderColor: '#f8f8f8',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
  },
  content: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.03,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.045,
  },
  left: {
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  center: {
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  right: {
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
});
```

and then on when you want to use the **Header** component you can set the `image` prop to `true`, eg:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Header from './components/Header';

export default () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header
        image
        imageSource={{ uri: 'https://yourimage.png' }}
        left={<Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-back" size={25} />}
        center={<Text>Projects</Text>}
        right={<Ionicons name="ios-camera" size={25} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image]

and then if you set the `image` prop to `false` you will remove the image from the background.

```js
<Header
  image={false}
  imageSource={{ uri: 'https://yourimage.png' }}
  left={<Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-back" size={25} />}
  center={<Text>Projects</Text>}
  right={<Ionicons name="ios-camera" size={25} />}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org)

You need to add a custon header component in navigationOptions,

```
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';


    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            header: (props) => <View >
                <LinearGradient
                    style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute' }}
                    start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} colors={['#1A9EAE', '#4EAE7C']}
                />
                <Header {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.transparent }} />
            </View>,
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<Header
        backgroundImage={require("../../assets/images/btn-header-background.png")}
        centerComponent={{
          text: i18n.t("stats.title"),
          style: { fontFamily: "FunctionLH", fontSize: 30, color: "#fff" }
        }}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          justifyContent: "space-around"
        }}
        statusBarProps={{ barStyle: "light-content" }}
      />
```